# HyperLedger Fabric E2E Scenario Not Working

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I want to use the end-2-end scenario to build my first network to invoke certificate authority containers. So, I just replaced the docker compose cli yaml file with the docker compose e2e.

```
# use this as the default docker-compose yaml definition
#COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose-cli.yaml
COMPOSE_FILE=docker-compose-e2e.yaml
```

But when I try to up this network I get the following error:

```
cli container not found
```

Why Its invoking CLI container. Can anyone please explain steps need to follow to setup this network with e2e docker compose.

Comment: docker-compose-e2e.yaml is designed to be used by SDKs and not use the CLI container. The docs tell you how to use e2e -> https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html?highlight=e2e

Comment: I read this document but this doesn't elaborate this section much. On which container then will we docker compose this e2e yaml file?

Comment: I'm newbie in hyperledger fiber technology. Can you please guide me a bit that (1) what is the difference between cli and e2e? (2) How can I setup network with e2e? (3) why is there no ca container in CLI? How certificates validations and other stuffs being performed then?

Comment: hi 1) one of the differences is e2e uses CA docker containers for the 2-org setup and the CLI yaml (`docker-compose-cli.yaml`, the default yaml in BYFN) doesn't :-) 2) see last comment below 3) already explained above . To start up the e2e yaml you can simply run (on the command line) something like (from the first-network directory in fabric-samples that you cloned): `./byfn.sh up -c mychannel -f docker-compose-e2e.yaml -s couchdb` (after first following the docs to get the binaries,tools (eg, cryptogen)) then running the cmd

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem with `docker-compose-e2e.yaml`. To run e2e tests we need cli container, but in `docker-compose-e2e.yaml` there is no service mentioned to start cli container.

On firing `./byfn.sh up -s couchdb -f docker-compose-e2e.yaml` it will start peers, couchdb, orderer containers, but failed to start cli container. Because their is no config for cli container.

To solve this just add cli service configuration in docker-compose-e2e.yaml

```
  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools:$IMAGE_TAG
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - SYS_CHANNEL=$SYS_CHANNEL
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      #- FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: /bin/bash
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/chaincode
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - peer1.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

Now on firing `./byfn.sh up -s couchdb -f docker-compose-e2e.yaml`. It will run e2e test.

I hope this will help.